# What are the things after prepositions called formally?

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis, objects

```
I eat rice from a bowl with a spoon.
```

`I` is the subject. `Rice` is the object. What are things like `bowl` and `spoon` called?

Comment: In your example, _rice_ is the object of the verb _eat_, _bowl_ is the object of the preposition _from_, and _spoon_ is the object of the preposition _with_. So, "object of a preposition." edit: and now Cerberus's answer has left my comment obsolete. Oh well.

Comment: Thank you for your comment; it was useful and appreciated. (Cerebrus's answer is a bit better though because my interpretation is that an "object of a preposition" need not always be a prepositional object in a sentence. For example, in "I drank the milk of a cow from a glass with a straw", "a cow" is the object of the preposition "of" but it is not the "prepositional object" of the verb "drink". The objects/prepositional-objects are "milk of a cow", "a glass", and "a straw".) Hope this helps.

Comment: @semantax: Right, there is no such thing as "the prepositional object of a verb": a prepositional object is the object of a preposition. The *prepositional phrase*, on the other hand, which includes both the preposition and its object, can be the argument, nay, even the complement of a verb—but not its object.

Comment: @Cerberus, so would your answer change if the sentence were "I drank the milk of a cow from a glass with a straw" and I asked what is the formal term for "the milk of a cow", "from a glass", "with a straw". Would you say these are *arguments* of the verb "drink"? That's the term I was looking for in my question. Sorry I didn't put a more general example.

Comment: @semantax: Yes, that is exactly right: those are arguments of the verb *drink*. One is the object of the verb, the others are prepositional phrases. // One thing to consider is that some arguments are almost "compulsory", the verb strongly expects them to be there, like the direct object and the subject of a verb: those are called *complements* to the verb. Other arguments are less compulsory and are called *satellites* or *adjuncts*. Sometimes prepositional phrases (while never objects to the verb) can be complements, as in *I went to Rome*—but not the ones in your examples.

Comment: P.S. Other words than verbs can of course have arguments too. In *I eat rice from a bowl*, the phrase *a bowl* is the primary argument of the preposition *from*, its object. So you can have arguments nested within arguments, *from a bowl* being itself an argument of the verb *drink*.

Comment: @Cerberus Thank you for the very lucid explanation! Your comments perfectly answer my question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*A bowl* and *a spoon* are **prepositional objects**, or the **objects of prepositions**.

Comment: Any reason why we can't call them 'indirect objects'? If it were Latin, in this instance 'bowl' and 'spoon' would both be *ablatives*.

Comment: No, a distinction is drawn between "indirect" and "prepositional" objects.  English sometimes allows a sentence be be rewritten such that a prepositional object becomes an indirect object or vice versa, but that does not make them the same.  For example:  "I sent **him** the letter." vs "I sent the letter to **him**."  First one is indirect, second one is prepositional.

Comment: @WS2 What case a given word in a given phrase would be in Latin does not have any bearing on how it should be analysed in English. These two here are not indirect object (not in Latin either—indirect objects are in the dative case in Latin). If it were in Finnish, the bowl would be in the elative case, and the spoon in the instructive (or more commonly, the adessive) case, but that doesn't tell us anything about what function the words have in _English_, either.

Comment: This accepted is to the original version of the question. Please do look at the discussion in comments between me and @Cerebrus on the main question to get a comprehensive and excellent answer! (In brief, the term I was looking for is "arguments of a verb".)